# Pdf generation with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn, prawnto

I need to generate PDFs with Rails 3.0.3.

Prawn + Prawnto looks great as [showed by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn)

But I cannot make his example works, the `table` function is not recognized by the `pdf` variable

Any insight on this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What do you need to generate from?  HTML templates?  Other documents? Ruby code?  Did you watch the screencast?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but personally I find wicked_pdf (https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) a much easier solution for generating PDFs in Rails. Firstly it's faster than Prawn, and secondly I can build the PDF using HTML, exactly the same as the rest of my app's views

Comment: Did you watch the screencast? --> yes! pdf.text and move_down works fine but not pdf.table

Comment: I'll have a look to Wicked PDF, thanks.

Comment: PDFkit works great as well http://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick fix, but not really happy with it...

adding `require 'prawn/layout'` to my view fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

open up prawn-core-0.8.4\lib\prawn\core.rb

at the bottom of that file you will see a list of all the 'require' items. I think this is where you should add require 'prawn/layout' if you do not want it in your views. still not ideal as you are customising the plugin.